# Faucet Supply Line Pinched

Tags: plumbing, faucet

We recently had to have our island cabinets replaced. To do this the contractor had to remove and reset the quartz countertop. It’s a decent sized chunk, about 9’ x 4’. During the installation of the countertop again the braided nylon supply lines for the faucet got pinched between the top of the cabinet and the quartz for about 30 seconds until they could tilt it up again to get the lines into the cabinet.

I’m mostly concerned with any effects this had on the durability of the lines; I felt them and couldn’t find any indentations or crimps and they currently hold water pressure with no issues. I’m wondering though if this crushing could cause a failure long before the normal service life end. They are integral to the faucet unfortunately so I can’t just swap them out. I just don’t know how tough these lines are or are meant to be.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is that our best answer would be "maybe..."; other than that I don't see how we could tell from here. (Sorry.)

Comment: I'll just add to the "maybe" by saying "but probably not". There is no way to tell for sure but as a gross general rule if it were damaged enough to fail, it would have done so immediately.